# What's the purpose of the TPL ContinueWith method?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, continuations

I'm confused about the TPL `ContinueWith` method.  I don't understand why it's needed.  [Here's an example from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537612(v=vs.110).aspx) that shows how to use `ContinueWith`:

```
static void SimpleContinuationWithState()
{
   int[] nums = { 19, 17, 21, 4, 13, 8, 12, 7, 3, 5 };
   var f0 = new Task<double>(() => nums.Average());
   var f1 = f0.ContinueWith(t => GetStandardDeviation(nums, t.Result));

   f0.Start();
   Console.WriteLine("the standard deviation is {0}", f1.Result);
}
```

It seems that I can remove the `ContinueWith` call without changing the results at all:

```
static void SimpleContinuationWithState()
{
   int[] nums = { 19, 17, 21, 4, 13, 8, 12, 7, 3, 5 };
   var f0 = new Task<double>(() => GetStandardDeviation(nums, nums.Average()));

   f0.Start();
   Console.WriteLine("the standard deviation is {0}", f0.Result);
}
```

This standard deviation example must be a contrived example, but I can't think of a reason to ever use ContinueWith.  (*unless some library call created the Task instead of me*)  In every case, can't I pull the ContinueWith call into the original Task?  It'll still run asynchronously.  There must be something I'm not understanding.

Comment: Look at the other overloads,  specifially the ones that take in a [`TaskContinuationOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: How would you do this if you were calling a method that already returned a `Task<T>`? The fact that you've got a contrived example where the original part really isn't asynchronous at all is unhelpful here... think about it as "I want to call a web service, then when that returns I want to call a second web service with the results of the first." Now think how you'd do that without ever blocking a thread.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I'd mark your comment as the answer if I could.  I didn't consider that situation.

Answer (score 3):

You're assuming that every single `Task` is just a synchronous method that's being run in a thread pool thread.  That's just not the case, and you shouldn't think of tasks that way.  A `Task` is some kind of work that will finish at some point, possibly generating a value as a result.  It could be running a method in a thread pool thread, it could be waiting for an event to fire, it could be waiting for the response to a network request, or for your hard drive to finish writing out some data to a file.

Yes, if your `Task` is specifically some synchronous code being run in a thread pool thread, and you *always* want some more synchronous code to run immediately after it on that same thread pool thread, and you're the one in control of creating that `Task`, and nothing else needs a `Task` representing that intermediate result, then you can just change what method to use to generate the `Task` as you showed (and if you are in that situation you're better of doing so).  That ends up being a reasonably narrow case though.

Answer (score 1):

As I describe on my blog, [there is exactly one use case for `ContinueWith`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html): [dynamic task parallelism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963551.aspx).

It should not be used for:'

- Asynchronous code.
- Data parallelism.
- Static task parallelism.

"Dynamic task parallelism" is when have a bunch of CPU-bound work to do that you want to use multiple threads for ("parallelism"), and you divide your work into multiple CPU-bound tasks ("task parallelism"), *and* you don't know how many tasks you'll need until you are already processing it ("dynamic task parallelism").

In other words, you should almost never use `ContinueWith`.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `.Result`  is a blocking operation, for synchronous code - in particular when you know the result is already there. Using `ContinueWith` is scheduling a callback for **when** the result becomes available - *async* code (although not via the `async`/`await` pattern). Note that if the result is *already* available, the continuation is invoked directly back onto the calling thread.

Your existing code is bad and can cause fatal deadlocks. Don't do it :) You are getting away with it *in this case*, but there are many many gotchas in anything that does "sync over async" (aka "calling `.Wait()` or accessing `.Result`).

Comment: I'm confused about how my code will deadlock.  If my continuation waits on the main thread in any way, I can see how I'd get a deadlock.  But the only blocking operation in my example is the `Result` property.

Comment: @user2023861 simple; if the `async` operation tries to do an `await`, by default it tries to invoke via the sync-context; the simplest example is something like winforms, but it applies equally to anything (asp.net, wcf, whatever); now - your UI thread has started an `async` operation, and some cogs are spinning in the background (network, etc); now the UI code from your example doesn't use `await`, but instead calls `.Result` or `.Wait()` - that means the UI thread is blocked waiting for the result. But the worker *itself* tries to send something to the UI thread to complete...

Comment: @user2023861 the operation, but that can't get executed until the UI thread is available. And the UI thread can't become available until the async operation completes. In a single word: deadlock. This is not an imaginary situation; there are plenty of questions here on SO asking why their code has blocked. I asked one myself! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621647/using-async-even-if-it-should-complete-as-part-of-a-mvc-route-deadlocks-the

Comment: I see. I thought you were talking about a potential deadlock in the code in my original post which was copied from MSDN.